# Higher Algebra, Section 2.2.2

Tags: higher-category-theory, simplicial-stuff, higher-algebra

I am reading Section 2.2.2 of Higher Algebra by Jacob Lurie. There are proofs which I cannot understand, so I need someone's help.

First, I cannot understand the proof of Lemma 2.2.7. In the proof, the following is claimed:

> Let $q \colon X \to S$ be an inner fibration of simplicial sets and let $Y$ be a simplicial set.
> Let us identify $\Delta^n \star Y$ with the full simplicial subset of $\Delta^n \times Y^{\triangleright}$ spanned by $\{\infty\}\times \Delta^n$ and $Y^{\triangleright} \times \{0\}$, where $\infty$ is the cone point of $Y^{\triangleright}$.
> Let $\overline{h_0}=\overline{h}\mid (\Delta^n\times Y) \coprod_{(\partial \Delta^n \times Y)} (\partial \Delta^n \times Y^{\triangleright})$, $\overline{g}=\overline{h}\mid (\Delta^n\star Y)$, and $g=\overline{h}\mid (\partial\Delta^n\star Y)$.
> Then the map $\theta \colon X_{\overline{h}/}\to X_{\overline{h_0}/}\times_{S_{q\overline{h_0}/}}S_{q\overline{h}/}$ is a pullback of the map
> $\theta^{\prime} \colon X_{\overline{g}/}\to X_{g/}\times_{S_{qg/}}S_{q\overline{g}/}$.

However, it seems to be wrong. I think that it is necessary to prove that for any simplicial set $Z$, $(\Delta^n \times Y^{\triangleright})\star Z$ is equal to $\left(\left((\Delta^n\times Y) \coprod_{(\partial \Delta^n \times Y)} (\partial \Delta^n \times Y^{\triangleright})\right)\star Z \right) \cup \left(\left(\Delta^n\star Y\right)\star Z\right)$. However, for example, for $n=1$, $Y=\Delta^0$, and $Z=\emptyset$, these doesn't coincide (the former one has 2 non-degenerate 2-simplices, but the latter one has 1 non-degenerate 2-simplex).

Second, I cannot understand the last part of the proof of Lemma 2.2.2.8, where the following is stated:

> Let $K, Y$ be simplicial sets, and let $Z$ be the full simplicial subset of $K^{\triangleright} \times Y^{\triangleright}$ obtained by removing the final object.
> Then  the inclusion $j \colon ((Y\star \partial \Delta^n)\times K^{\triangleright})\coprod_{((Y\star \partial \Delta^n)\times K)}((Y\star \Delta^n)\times K) \to ((Y\star \Delta^n)\times K^{\triangleright})$ is a pushout of the inclusion $i\colon Z\star \partial \Delta^n\to Z\star \Delta^n$.

However I think that it doesn't hold. For example, let $Y=K=\Delta^0$ and $n=1$, then $(\Delta^0\star \Delta^1)\times (\Delta^0)^{\triangleright}=\Delta^2\times\Delta^1$ has 3 non-degenerate 3-simplices which aren't contained in $((\Delta^0\star \partial \Delta^1)\times \Delta^1)\coprod_{((\Delta^0\star \partial \Delta^1)\times \Delta^0)}((\Delta^0\star \Delta^1)\times \Delta^0)$ (this simplicial set is 2-dimensional), but $Z\star \Delta^1 =\Lambda^2_0\star \Delta^1$ has only 2 non-degenerate 3-simplices which aren't contained in $Z\star \partial \Delta^1$. In fact, I cannot find the natural map from $i$ to $j$.

There are also a few other parts which I cannot understand. For example, I cannot understand the first step and the first diagram of the proof of Lemma 2.2.2.9.

So my question is: **Am I misunderstanding or overlooking something? If I am not, are there some alternative ways to prove the results of Section 2.2.2?**
I would appreciate any relevant comments.

Comment: There are different models of the join which one can use. Does it help to plug in a different model of the join?